# Android :How to Spinner Look like textView and Onclick on spinner open dialog with custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-spinner

Please anyone can tell me how to design this layout with spinner

**this is my 1st screen with spinner**

[image]

**this is my screen which open the dialog box with custon listview onclick of select city spinner**

[image]

and onselecting Dialog item it display in 1st screen  which is functionality of spinner ..

**Please** anyone can suggest me how to do this ...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried to set onClickListener to the text view? Inside of onClick() method you can show your custom dialog with listview.

Comment: yes ,But my issue is ,dependency like when I select country then automatically change the cities .So I am using spinner because its onItemSelected method is useful

Comment: So, in spinner adapter you can inflate your custom UI for your spinner. Do not forgot to override properly getDropDownView() and getView() methods

Comment: thanks adapter design is handle but , how to spinner look like textview

Comment: I will add an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix:

- Create a custom relative layout and put a spinner to the place where writes pune on first screen. Make spinners background transparent or the same color as relative layout.
- Set spinners mode dialogMode from xml:

  android:spinnerMode="dialog"
- Set a new onClickListener to your relative layout and put in:

  mySpinner.performClick();
- Finally in your spinner adapter define your custom spinner row layout like in second screen.

Comment: i cannot understand what you mean exactly when you say "look like a textview" but if you set spinner's background transparent i think it'll look like a textview.

Comment: I mean Spinner view look like simple textview and on click open dialog   with list . I set property of spinner spinnerMode="dialog" , but how to SpinnerView look like simple textview

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below steps.

1) Have a TextView instead of Spinner, RegisterOnclick Listener on it.

2) on onClick event, start a dialog with list view. [Tutorial](http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-alert-dialog-with-listview-and.html)

3) get Item Selected from Listview/Dialog, set it again in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your layout with text view in spinner_layout.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/id_of_your_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Adapter class do:

```
//members
    protected Context context;
    protected LayoutInflater inflater;
//constructor
public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
//override method getView
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_textView);
            textView.setText("blah-blah");
            return element;
        }
```

It should be enough.
If your spinner items should show complex item, do not forget to override 
getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method.